# navigate the scope variables in developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

As I'm learning Javascript, I'm frequently inspecting my scope variables to get a better understanding of how things work.

I find that I'm frequently scrolling through the scope variables to find the variable that I am interested in.  Is there a way that I can quickly navigate to the specific variable I am looking for ***without*** having to scroll?

Comment: You can just type the variable name in the console to let it be printed, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Is there a way to view the full object structure in the console?

Comment: You can click the `>` arrow to expand an object.

Comment: Clicking `>` has no effect.  Maybe I'm running an old version of chrome (43.0.2357.134)

Comment: Same version here, if I set a breakpoint and type `this` in the console, I get `> Object {}`, where I can click `>` to expand.

Comment: To view the the full structure in the console just use `console.dir(obj)`

Comment: @Garbee Perfect - thanks!  If you add this as an answer, I can credit you :)

Comment: That isn't answering the primary question though. I need to look into that more since it should be possible to filter them. Probably via Ctrl + F, but that may trigger search across the sources panel itself instead of the variables side panel.