# Programmatically accessing [[Scopes]] (closure variables) through Chrome DevTools API or panel? (Not at breakpoint)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, closures, google-chrome-devtools, inspect

In 2014, it was [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25672346/2877364) for JS code to access variables inside a closure from outside the closure.  Since then, Chrome's internals [have changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45508961/2877364) to use `[[Scopes]]` instead of `Closure`.

Is it now (2018) possible for Chrome DevTools to read `[[Scopes]]` programmatically?  If so, is there an existing DevTools extension that does so?

Use case: inspecting variables inside a UMD module loaded using RequireJS.  I know I can do this [at a breakpoint](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OHwby4dA_mM) or `debugger` statement using the `Scopes` panel, but would like to be able to do so even when I am not at a breakpoint.

**Edit** As of 2017, it was [not possible to access `[[FunctionLocation]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41146373/2877364), but I don't know about `[[Scopes]]`.

#### Attempts

I have investigated the following without success (module factory function name `main`):

- [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500637/navigate-the-scope-variables-in-developer-tools#comment50964452_31500637) mentions `console.dir()`, but there is no programmatic access to the output of `console.dir()`.  I can use `console.dir({main})` and then expand the results manually, but not programmatically.
- From the DevTools console, I can use `inspect({function})` per [this](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/117-inspect-function-scope/).  That gets me closer, but not to `[[Scopes]]`:

  ```
  > var x = inspect({main})
  > x.main.name
  ← "main"
  > x.main[Symbol('Scopes')]
  ← undefined
  > x.main['[[Scopes]]']
  ← undefined
  ```
- The [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow) API provides an [`eval` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#method-eval) that can use [`inspect`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#inspect).  However, I can't get from the `inspect` results to `[[Scopes]]`, as noted above.

#### Notes

- Posting a new question rather than bumping the [2014 one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25672346/2877364) as suggested by [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258367/2877364)
- Different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8458561/2877364) because I am trying to access module internals rather than the public module interface

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146373/access-function-location-programmatically

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks - I did see that one but forgot to link it in the question.  Any difference between `[[FunctionLocation]]` and `[[Scopes]]` in terms of access rights?

Comment: You still cannot programmatically access them (from code in the page or in the console). That they changed the name under which they display that internal property doesn't change anything.

Comment: A devtools extension might be able to do this however. Is that what you want to create?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, if there isn't already a devtools extension, I would be delighted to create one :) .  However, I cannot find access to `[[Scopes]]` in the DevTools API docs linked in the question.  I am hoping someone can point me to an API I'm missing.

Comment: @cxw  [devtools API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) is indeed disappointing. It seems very restricted and only allows light customisation, such as getting the currently inspected windows and adding own panels to the devtools view, but there is no access to the internal data structures. It seems that you should focus on the [debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) which allows you to access the runtime objects, and also gain access to [internal properties](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#type-InternalPropertyDescriptor)