# What's the execution context of a module in JavaScript? How do I access it explicitly in the browser's console?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, using modules requires setting the value of the `type` attribute to `module` on `script` tags. While doing so, I noticed that I cannot access initialized variables from the browser's console. It would seem that modules have their own scope outside of the `window` object.

In the following snippet, I try to access `window.foo` while using`type=module`.
This fails as it only exists in what I guess is the module's scope.

```js
<script type="module">
    var foo = 40;
    console.log(foo); // 40
    console.log(window.foo); // undefined
</script>
```

Here, I try do the same thing without `type="module"`.

```js
<script>
    var foo = 40;
    console.log(foo); // 40
    console.log(window.foo); // 40
</script>
```

**How can I access that scope explicitly from the global scope / browser's console?**

Comment: You can't. Each module has its own scope. Only exported values can be accessed. There might be a  way to switch the "context" in the browser console but that would depend on the browser (this is just a guess based on how browsers allow to do that with iframes).

Answer (score 2):

> It would seem that modules have their own scope

Yes, that's one of their major selling points.

> How can I access that scope explicitly from the global scope?

You cannot - again, by design.

> How can I access that scope explicitly from the browser's console?

You need to set a breakpoint on some code inside the module, where that scope is visible, or inspect a closure that comes from the module.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you describe in your last sentence? I'd gladly accept that answer.

Comment: @shellwhale See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52150979/1048572) or [some screenshots](https://www.google.com/search?q=closure+scopes+devtools&source=lnms&tbm=isch)