# What does [[Scopes]] represent in javascript and how to access them?

Tags: javascript, scope

I found this structure in my project [[Scopes]] and I never seen it before. What might it refer to or how can I access those objects?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150979/programmatically-accessing-scopes-closure-variables-through-chrome-devtool?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You're not supposed to access those objects. They're not part of javascript but is used by your browser internally to present you debugging information in the developer tools