# Where is the outer scope variable stored in the revealing module pattern after composing a new object?

Tags: javascript

I have a revealing module pattern.

Let me understand where the variable `val` is stored after calling `createCounter()` in `counter1` and `counter2`.

`createCounter` creates object including `increment()` and `getVal()` methods in `counter1` and `counter2`. If we console.log these two variables we get objects. But where is the `val` stored?

Does two different `val` exist in corresponding scope of the variables `counter1` and `counter2`? The concept just does not click in my mind.

Can we anyhow console `val` which corresponds to `counter1` and `counter2`?

```
function createCounter() {
    let val = 0;
    return {
        increment() { val++ },
        getVal() { return val }
    }
}

let counter1 = createCounter();
counter1.increment();
console.log(counter1.getVal()); // 1
counter1.increment();
console.log(counter1.getVal()); // 2


let counter2 =  createCounter();
console.log(counter2.getVal()) // 0
```

Comment: Each time you call `createCounter()`, a new `val` is stored into memory with scope of `createCounter`. The returned functions hold references to that specific `val` variable, meaning multiple creations of `createCounter` do not reference the same `val`. However, you have to be careful here as you could possibly memory leak if you don't properly dispose of the value.

Comment: What would be the right way to dispose it though?

Comment: "*I have a revealing module pattern.*" - [no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22906662/1048572). You have a (factory) function returning an object with closures.

Comment: "*Can we anyhow console val which corresponds to counter1 and counter2?*" - you [could once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70718302/1048572), but [not any longer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75016334/1048572). Now the only way is to place a breakpoint in `getVal` and call it.

Comment: `What would be the right way to dispose it` - it is automatically garbage collected in a similar way other variables inside a function are disposed of. When you delete the variables `counter1` and `counter2` or assign some other values to them (eg. `counter1 = 'hello'`) the memory used by `val` attached to them gets garbage collected.